# Unable to stop the listener in oracle 10g

Tags: java, linux

when i am stopping the listener, getting following error message...

**LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Production on 01-JUN-2012 12:21:31
Copyright (c) 1991, 2007, Oracle. All rights reserved.
NL-00857: wrong number (0 - 1 needed) of arguments to "stop"**

I am using following command to stop the listener..

**$ORACLE_HOME/bin/lsnrctl stop LISTENER**

when i execute the command through command prompt then it works but through java it fails.

Please help me to resolve this problem....

Comment: Add code how do you try to do it from Java.

Comment: String cmdStr = "env ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1 /u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/bin/lsnrctl stop LISTENER";                                                           Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdStr);

Answer (score 0):

I think your java cmdStr is not correct; you can't just put a space between commands (setting the env variable then calling lsnrctl).  You need to use a semicolon:

```
String cmdStr="env ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1;/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/bin/lsnrctl stop LISTENER";
```

Comment: I tried this but still problem is there.  It syas....env: status: Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

`env` is a bash command, so you can't exec it from java. You can either make that into a short shell script and exec that from java or you can do the following

```
String cmd = "/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/bin/lsnrctl stop LISTENER";
String[] envp = "ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1";
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, envp);
if (proc.waitFor() != 0) {
    throw new RuntimeException("exit value was nonzero");
}
```